# How to wait an arbitrary amount of time in nightwatch.js without web browser interaction

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js

I'm migrating my tests from Intern.js to Nightwatch.js and I'm sure it's not the *recommended* way of writing tests, but my tests asynchronously make `browser` command calls (my tests use a class that has its own command queue). The Nightwatch command queue can be empty sometimes depending on what's executing, but will eventually be populated. I need a way to manually tell Nightwatch when it's done, and just wait until then, otherwise the browser will close too early.

I can do something like this:

```js
finished() {
  let done = false;
  //will run at the end of my class's internal command queue
  this.command
    .then(() => {
      done = true;
    });
    
  //will cause nightwatch to wait until my command queue is done
  this.browser.perform(doneFn => {
    const check = () => {
      if (done) {
        return doneFn();
      }
      setTimeout(check, 10);
    }
    check();
  });
}
```

But in that case `perform()` will time out after waiting 10 seconds, and I don't seem to be able to configure that. I could otherwise run a sequence of ~9 second `perform()` calls but it just sounds too hacky. I could rewrite to depend on nightwatch command queue instead, but that'd also be a lot more work to rewrite everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was easier to just switch to depending on using nightwatch's command queue instead. Anything that was just a `.then()` with Intern.js got changed to a `.perform()` in its various forms.